# How to make filter to be viewed in html

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

On my home page I added a button named 'city'. On clicking it opens a popup listing the city names. On clicking the city 'paris' the data with city name must be displayed.

**homepage**

```
 <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-subheader">   
            <button class="button button-flat button-positive"ng-click="citypopup();" style="padding-right: 63px;
    padding-left: 18px;"> 
                <l >City </l>
                <l class="icon ion-chevron-down"></l>
            </button>

    </ion-header-bar> 

    <ion-content> 
          <div class='card ' ng-repeat="item in list  | filter:test.searchCity ">
                 <div class="list "  >
                    <div class='item' style="padding-top:0px;" >  {{item.id}}
                        <l class="item-icon-right" style="padding-left:30%"> {{item.date}} </l>
                    </div>

                    <div class='item' style="padding-top:0px;" >{{item.status }}
                        <l class="item-icon-right" style="text-align:right;">{{item.QCstatus}}</l>
                        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right"></i>
                    </div>
                    <b class='item '> {{item.Factory}} </b>
                    <l class='item '>{{item.city }}</l>
                </div>
```

**popup page**

```
<ion-list> 
    <ul class="list" ng-model="test.searchCity" ng-repeat="ci in cityList | orderBy:'city' " >
        <li class="item" ng-click="test.searchCity">{{ci.city}}  </li>      
    </ul>
</ion-list>
```

**javascript**

```
$scope.test = {
    searchCity: null,       
};

$scope.cityList = [
    {
        "city": "Chennai"
    }, {
        "city": "Banglore"
    }, {
        "city": "Delhi"
    }
];

$scope.list = [
    {  
        id: "#001",
        date:"DEC 04 2016",
        status: "Successful",
        QCstatus: "Approve",
        Factory: "ARUN ICE CREAM",
        city: "paris"
    },
    {
        id: "#002",
        date: "JAN 11 2016",
        status: "Successful",
        QCstatus: "Approve",
        Factory: "Floxtronics",
        city: "Delhi"
    },
    {
        id: "#003",
        date: "Feb 14 2016",
        status: "Bug fixing",
        QCstatus: "Approve",
        Factory: "Aachi",
        city: "Chennai"
    }           
];

$scope.$watch('test.searchCity', function () {
    $scope.test.searchCity = null;
    console.log('test.searchCity')
});

$scope.citypopup = function() {
    var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
        scope: $scope,
        templateUrl: 'templates/cityTemplate.html',    
        buttons: [
            { text: 'Cancel',
             type: 'button-positive' },            
        ]
    });

}
```

What I need is when I click 'city' button, my city popup appears and when I click on a city nothing happens! Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to create another popup page, you can open popup content in **citypopup()** *function*

```
$scope.citypopup = function() {
  $scope.popup = $ionicPopup.show({         
      template:"<ion-list><ul class='list' ng-model='test.searchCity' ng-repeat='ci in cityList | orderBy:city ' ><li class='item' ng-click='searchCity(ci.city)'>{{ci.city}}  </li> </ul></ion-list>" ,
      title: 'City',
      scope: $scope        
  });
}

$scope.searchCity = function(city){
   $scope.test.searchCity = city;    
   $scope.popup.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never assign `test.searchCity`.

In you popup page code you use `ng-click="test.searchCity"`, where you probably should use `ng-click="test.searchCity = ci.city"`.

Unrelated to your problem (but a matter of correct use of patterns): No need for `ngModel` in a `ul` element (it's only for form elements), and `ng-repeat` makes more sense when used on `li`s rather than `ul`s.

In conclusion:

```
<ion-list> 
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="item" ng-repeat="ci in cityList | orderBy:'city' " ng-click="test.searchCity = ci.city">{{ci.city}}  </li>      
    </ul>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: when i click on a city inside popup i want popup to be closed and that specific city to be displayed but this does not happens in my code